# Magnitude of Resistance

Tags: proof-explanation, physics, classical-mechanics

[question and diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFLaT.png)

I have this question (attached image) and I can't seem to work out how to go about answering it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are your results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the box is moving at constant speed, the net force is zero.  That is, the resistance due to friction is equal in magnitude to the component of $150$ N and the component of $100$ N in the direction opposite to the friction.  Because the angles are special, you should know that the component of $150$ N at $45^\circ$ in that direction is $150/\sqrt2,$ and the component of $100$ N at $30^\circ$ in that direction is $100\sqrt3/ 2$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, thank you so much!